# Calculus of Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I finding difficulties calculating : $res(f,0)$.

with $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2sinz}$

I thought of the method : defining $g(z)=z^3f(z)$, since $0$ is a pole of order $3$.

then : $res(f,0)=\frac{1}{2!}g^{(2)}(0).$

but calculating the 2nd derivative is harder; I tried to find the Laurent series but I couldn't :

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2(z-z^3/3!+O(z^5))}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing your argument:

$$
g(z)=z^3 f(z)=f(z)=\frac{z^3}{z^2 \sin(z)}=\frac{z}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{h(z)}
$$

$$
h(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1 - \frac{z^2}{6} + \frac{z^4}{120} + \cdots
$$
Write
$$
g(z) = g_0 + g_1 z + g_2 z^2 + g_3 z^3 + \cdots
$$
Then
$$
1 = g(z)h(z) =  g_0 + g_1 z + (g_2 - \frac{g_0}{6}) z^2 + \cdots
$$
and so
$$
g_2=\frac{g_0}{6}= \frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: The third line its like you suppose that $g$ is analytic in neighborhood of $0$, (because you didn't mentioned the principal part of Laurent Serie). and please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: You said it yourself: $g(z)=z^3f(z)$ is analytic in neighborhood of $0$ since $0$ is a pole of order $3$ of $f$.

Comment: Excuse me, I thought of it as $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Either way is a bit of work.  The first few terms of the Laurent series can be found by long division (as you've outlined):

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{6z} + \frac{7z}{360} + \textrm{higher order terms}$$

The residue is the coefficient in front of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z}$:

$$\textrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z)=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Can I do my calculus (2nd derivative) unsing $z^3f(z)=\frac{z^3}{z^2(z-z^3/3!+O(z^5))}$, instead of $\frac{z}{sinz}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  I haven't worked it out, you may (or may not) need one more term in the expansion.